# What does a greyed out view in the Android Layout Inspector mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-layout-editor

In Android Studio, Tools -> **Layout Inspector**, what does a greyed out(subdued, dim) view in the View Tree mean? The layer still has `VISIBLE` properties

I don't see any explanation in the docs, https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector and there isn't a tooltip when hovering the view.

You can [download the `.li` layout capture in question here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitter/gitter-android-app/uploads/c75fc72a917d379e28454c6c5c8bfd77/im.gitter.gitter_2018.12.11_23.09.li)

[image]

---

For context/reference, I am trying to figure out why the fragment isn't showing up in the `id/content_container`, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitter/gitter-android-app/issues/108

The project is open source if you want to check out the code yourself, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitter/gitter-android-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these nodes are boilerplate layout, which are essential for the framework.

that `ContentFrameLayout` is the root-view with id `android.R.id.content`,

which has `R.layout.activity_main` inflated and it adds further nested nodes into there.

basicallyy it's name-space `android.R` (in gray) vs. `im.gitter.gitter.R` (in black).

nodes from `android.R` might still turn black, when they have a visble layout inflated.

Comment: What about this case where there are child elements? https://i.imgur.com/aIfIESr.png

I do see `INVISIBLE` on `NavigationView` though?

Perhaps it ties in with nothing drawing/rendering?

Comment: @MLM that child element there might also be boilerplate, without a custom view inflated; they need to be there, because else the framework would throw NPE. I've also checked https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitter/gitter-android-app/tree/master/app/src/main/res/layout ...just not sure which one it is.

Comment: For reference, it's in the [`app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitter/gitter-android-app/blob/0ff8428f6e2fc310bdb5dd7a7d61a2a7b2dd53ac/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) and associated [`app/src/main/java/im/gitter/gitter/activities/MainActivity.java`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitter/gitter-android-app/blob/0ff8428f6e2fc310bdb5dd7a7d61a2a7b2dd53ac/app/src/main/java/im/gitter/gitter/activities/MainActivity.java)

Comment: What is considered layout boilerplate? Why aren't other `FrameLayout`, `ContentFrameLayout`, `LinearLayout` in grey?

Comment: @MLM that `ContentFrameLayout`is the root-view with id `android.R.id.content`, which has `R.layout.activity_main` inflated and it adds further nested nodes into there. which originate from the custom xml. when looking at `MainActivity.java`, there is no `NavigationView` header being inflated; if you'd add a custom header into there, it shouldn't be grayed out anymore (just to proof what I'm telling). updated the answer, too... and that name-space thing, seems to be the best explanation - because it is the difference in between framework vs. app resources.

Answer (score 6):

The grayed-out `View`s are not rendered at the time when the LayoutInspector snapshot is taken because they don't need to be shown.

Examples:

- the `NavigationView` in your code is currently hidden (you can test if I'm right by opening it and taking another snapshot with LayoutInspector)
- the `RecyclerView` in the `NavigationView` is grayed-out as long as it has no Adapter assigned to it (and maybe also if it is empty - did not test it)
- sometimes `View`s don't fit on the screen, like when you forget to make a `LinearLayout` "vertical" and so most of its children are to the right of the right screen edge